# Identification of red, plum-like fruit (probably from Southern Russia)

Tags: species-identification, botany

My parents are currently on a holiday in St. Petersburg (Russia). They sent me this photo of plum-like fruits they bought on a market there (toilet paper for scale, I guess).

[image]

The fruits are 20-30mm long, have a big stone, taste sourly like red currant (based on my fathers opinion) and are supposed to come from Southern Russia (don't know where this information is coming from).

Can you please help to identify them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be certain from the picture, but they look a lot like Cornelian Cherry (Cornus mas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_mas ).  However, the ones in my garden (western US) don't ripen until late September/October.

Perhaps they could return to the market, and ask for the Russian name?

Comment: I think that's it. The pear shape, the red color, the acidic taste, the origin... everything fits. Of course this can't be verified, but I consider this question answered. Thanks!

Comment: I don't notice an acid taste with mine, more of an astringent, mouth-puckering taste until they're fully ripe, when they turn deep red, start to wrinkle a bit, and almost fall off the bush by themselves.  That said, I don't think they're at all good eaten fresh. but they make really great jam and fruit leather.  Search the web for recipes :-)